# Describing vortices using Gross-Pitaevskii equation

Tags: bose-einstein-condensate

A lot of the description of vortices starts by saying a vortex in a Bose-Einstein condensate can be generated by imparting an angular momentum to the container. So  as I understand it is described by a Hamiltonian of the form

$$ H= (p^2/2m + V_{ext} + g\lvert\psi\rvert^2)\psi - \Omega L_z\psi $$

But then when proceeding to analyse the form of the vortex, $\psi=fe^{i\phi}$ form is used and plugged into the GP equation, without any angular momentum term (for a free vortex solution away from effects of external potentials).
So I don't completely understand how GP equation is a good model for describing these vortices. A vortex solution clearly has more energy than the solution without any vortex, and if we remove the angular momentum term from the Hamiltonian, I dont see how solving GP equation with some boundary conditions can lead to vortex solutions. If such a state of the system existed, won’t the system try to minimise its energy and go to the lower energy state which does not have any vortices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Hamiltonian with the $-\Omega L_z$ is the one you would use for the thermodynamics of a system that it is in equilibrium in a  rotating frame of reference. Clearly it encourages motion with a postive $L_z$ as such motion has lower energy. If $\Omega$ is large enough the ground state in the rotating frame will contain vortices.

The GP equation is perfectly good for describing vortices, however.  It is just that the vortices  are *excited states* when seen from the viewpoint of the non-rotating laboratory frame --- they cost energy to make.  If you put in a vortex solution by hand (by setting $\psi= f(r)e^{i\theta}$ then you have supplied the necessary energy. The $-\Omega L_z$ with
$$
L_z= \int d^3x \frac 1{2m} \psi^* (x\partial_y-y\partial_x) \psi
$$
does not affect the vortex solution significantly.  In particular the vortices can't just dissappear as they are protected by the topological phase-winding number.

Comment: If a vortex is an exited state, will it be well described by the GP equation? since the GP equation is obtained by minimizing the total energy for a system with N particles. Or is it the case that the difference between the vortex energy state and a non-vortex energy state is small enough that the GP equation is still an almost valid description?

Comment: The time-dependent  GP equation (aka the non-linear Schroedinger equation)  is a mean-field approximation  to the many-body bose field theory. It does not involve minimizing any energy. It can, however,  be derived as a   stationary *action* solution of the Bose-theory Lagrangian.